# Is there something faster than a min heap for my use case?

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures

My use case is as follows:

1. I need to get the minimum of a set of growing elements; I'll only need the minimum for any iteration
2. I will update the minimum value after which it is guaranteed to no longer be the minimum but its new position in the order is not in general calculable directly.
3. I push this new value back onto the collection and go to the next iteration where I look at the new min element.

Right now I'm using a std::vector and std::pop_heap std::push_heap in the following way. I call std::pop_heap on my vector which pushes the min element to the back of the vector, I get a reference to the last element and I update it, then I call std::push_heap which moves the last element to its new location. So I don't have to copy the struct out of the std::vector to update it currently. The struct in question is 16 bytes and trivially constructible, its pretty basic consisting entirely of integral types.

According to my profiler and across a range of problem sizes what I'm seeing is that I'm spending >75% of my cpu time in std::pop_heap and ~10% in std::push_heap. Now the logic being performed on each minimum element that gets checked is pretty trivial consisting mostly of additions and a few comparisons to a fixed input so I suppose that it is possible that this is as good as it gets. However if there is a different or random weird data structure that might be faster than the min_heap I'm currently using it would be fun to try out.

I've tried std::min_element, std::nth_element, std::sort each of which takes my current solution times of less than 1 second for a problem size of 1,000,000 or less and increases the run time by orders of magnitude (many 10's of seconds). Which I would expect given that they all have a worse complexity than std::push_heap and std::pop_heap.

I've also tried using tree structures like std::map and std::set but these also degrade performance (I don't have numbers handy right now).

So does anybody know of something better than a min_heap for this use case?

(Unfortunately I can't provide the source code but given that 85% of the cpu time is spent on pop_heap/push_heap I don't think it would be super useful anyways)

Edit: The comparison operator is a single comparison between two integral types. so its not like the comparison operator being used in the heap is doing a massive amount of work.

Comment: When you update the minimum value, is its new position typically closer to the root or closer to the "end" of the heap?

Comment: Have you tried a sorted vector that does not include the deleted element but stores the minimum value of all deleted elements and inserts them again if the minimum is smaller?

Comment: How many times does your code call `push_heap()` and `pop_heap()` per iteration?  Ideally it would just be one of each, per iteration (as you pop the minimum-value out of the heap, update it, then push it back in), plus one `push_heap()` call for each new item you happen to push into the set-of-elements at the same time.  If it's more than that, check to make sure you aren't doing something inefficient (like clearing the heap and repopulating it from scratch on each iteration)

Comment: @harold usually its closer to the min rather than the max but this is not guaranteed for any given iteration.

Comment: @henk the elements aren't deleted they are modified and pushed back, the value of the minimum element grows slowly over the life of the algorithm

Comment: @JeremyFriesner in each iteration there is one pop_heap and one push_heap if we find a new item we need to track we  have the occasional second push_heap. Its definitely _not_ clearing and rebuilding the heap each iteration

Comment: Sometimes when you find yourself writing a process like this, each new value tends to be larger than all the previous new values.  If that's the case, then there are faster ways than pushing the new values back into a heap of the old ones.

Comment: @MattTimmermans so I have looked at that and unfortunately each updated value tends to be in the middle of the heap values but in extreme cases will go towards either end of the heap. so its not really possible to precompute the new position for the updated values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than removing the minimum element and reinserting the updated value, you could change the value in-place and down-bubble from the root. Removing the minimum element often replaces it with one of the worst elements to replace the root with, typically costing a *long* down-bubble, and then reinserting a relatively small value costs a relatively long up-bubble as well. Changing the key in-place replaces both of those taken together with just one down-bubble, which is also typically shorter, as long as the new value stays relatively close to the root on average.

Sadly there is no function for this in `<algorithm>`, but it's not too difficult to roll your own. Write it in terms of *moves* into a "hole" left by making a temporary copy of the root, not as a series of `std::swap`s. Doing it with swaps works out to about double the number of loads and stores in total.

Using a [heap of larger *arity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap) (probably 4, maybe 8) may help.

Comment: updating in place and writing my own pushdown method is something I've not tried yet so I'll definitely look into that, not sure how increasing the arity would affect things in this instance but also worth a look; thanks!

Comment: So I checked out implementing my own siftdown algorithm for the heap and modifying the min element in place, and that got me 30-60% depending on the problem size. now my profiler is pointing to individual comparison operators so I think to improve further I need to store less state as I go along :)